# fix case sensitive URL

Tags: url, .htaccess, filelink

I have been doing some work on my localhost with xampp and I have a link that looks like this

```
http://localhost/Example
```

and another one called

```
http://localhost/example
```

The actual folder name is called example in lower case but either one works.
However I have moved the files onto a ubuntu aws instance and it doesn't work there.

What do I need to do to handle urls so they aren't case sensitive in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mod_speling`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html)<sup>1</sup>. Add the following code to `.htaccess`:

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

These two directives will turn on spell checking, then restrict it to only fixing case errors. This will affect all levels in the URL, for example `http://localhost/ExAmPle/someFILE` would be fixed to `http://localhost/example/someFile` if the latter does indeed exist.

If both cases exist on disk, then the user will be presented with a choice page.

<sup>1</sup>The misspelling of the name is a purposeful action by the authors.